# How do I view and delete an admin migration

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I tried running my Django project and I got a warning on unapplied migrations.
The problem is, I didn't make any changes that would arouse any migration so I set out to look for the migration files but I couldn't find any. 
I ran `python manage.py showmigrations` to see the migrations that were pending
I then discovered there were two admin migrations that were pending
`[ ] 0004_auto_20200124_1105`
`[ ] 0005_auto_20200124_1107`
I've been trying all day to trace these files or to even see the changes to no avail. Please help

Answer (score 0):

migrate command basically stores your data in database, if you want to delete those entries like say you made a mistake in your models file now you want to delete that model from database. Now, to do that just click on the app you created, it will listout a subfolder called migrations click on that, it will open up some files like pycache, below it something like 0001_initial.py and few more files like this (you will get your above mentioned files here). Just delete these numeric files if you want to clean your database of this app. (works for every IDE)

[image]

Comment: But these are admin migrations and there is no admin "app", so I do not have access to the admin migrations folder to be able to view said migrations

Comment: i dint understand. what permissions ? just open the IDE and locate above steps and delete those files as you said you are tracing these files. See above picture (i edited my answer)

Comment: @iyokeose"admin" is [a django.contrib app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/).